# CakePHP 4 - Unknown method "loadModel"

Tags: cakephp

In a CakePHP 4 application I've added this to a model, `src/Model/Table/SignUpsTable.php`

```
 public function initialize(array $config): void
 {
     parent::initialize($config);
     // ...
     $this->loadModel('EmailDomains');
 }
```

I have a model called `EmailDomains` and the appropriate Table/Entity class files exist.

In a controller method I have the following:

```
// src/Controller/UsersController.php
public function initialize(): void
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadModel('SignUps');
}

public function signUp()
{
   // ...
}
```

When navigating to `/sign-up` in my browser it gives the following error:

> Unknown method "loadModel" called on App\Model\Table\SignUpsTable

If I comment-out the `loadModel` code in `SignUpsTable::initialize` it clears this error but then other code I have in there won't work as it references `$this->EmailDomains->...`

Answer (score 1):

That's because `loadModel` is in fact not a method in that class.

[`\TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('EmailDomains')`](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/table-objects.html#getting-instances-of-a-table-class) will return the table object (which you can reference directly if you just need it once, or save in a local variable or class property)

Or if you `use Cake\Datasource\ModelAwareTrait;` in your particular table class, then the `loadModel` function should become available to you.

Comment: Is there any way to find out what `use` statements you'd need? For example how do you know it's `ModelAwareTrait` for `loadModel()` since these aren't named in a way anyone would intuitively realise?

Comment: Also with regards to "if you `use Cake\Datasource\ModelAwareTrait` ... " this doesn't actually work. Results in the same error message as in the question. I've put it in the appropriate Table class.

Comment: CakePHP is just PHP, so you can search the source to find where functions are defined. Or if you're using any kind of modern IDE, there's probably a way to jump from a valid use (e.g. in a controller) to the definition of the function.

Comment: Where did you put your `use` statement? Inside the class definition, or just at the very top of the file?

Comment: At the top of the file with the rest of them

Comment: Look up how to use traits in PHP, you need to *also* `use` the trait class name *inside* the class itself.